# JSRuntime in Blazor WebAssembly blocking DOM updates on first load

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-client-side, blazor-jsinterop

I'm using the latest [Blazor WebAssembly 3.2.0 Release Candidate](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/blazor-webassembly-3-2-0-release-candidate-now-available/)

From a vanilla Blazor WASM template I made the following adjustments to test/debug the issue:

In **Program.cs** I add the following singleton that will be injected into all pages:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ApplicationState>();
```

The class looks like:

```
public class ApplicationState
{
    public bool BoolValue { get; set; }
    public string StringValue { get; set; }

    public ApplicationState()
    {
        BoolValue = false;
        StringValue = "Default value";
    }

}
```

and is injected in **_Imports.razor** along with JSRuntime so they are available to all pages:

```
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime
@inject BlazorApp1.State.ApplicationState AppState;
```

In order to test that the ApplicationState object is passing through the application properly I have it used in the following 2 locations:

In **NavManu.razor** I wrap one of the menu items around **BoolValue** to show/hide that item:

```
@if (AppState.BoolValue)
{
    <li class="nav-item px-3">
        <NavLink class="nav-link" href="counter">
            <span class="oi oi-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Counter
        </NavLink>
    </li>
}
```

And in **Index.razor** I added an H2 tag under the default Hello World header to display the **StringValue**

```
<h1>Hello, world!</h1>
<h2>@AppState.StringValue</h2>
```

I also have a javascript file located in **wwwroot/js/extenstions.js** it has a single function used to get cookie data:

```
function getCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
    }
    return null;
};
```

And is included as a script in the **wwwroot/index.html** right below the **_framework/blazor.webassembly.js** script:

```
<script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
<script src="js/extensions.js"></script>
```

In **App.razor** I have the following **@code** block:

```
@code
{
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        AppState.BoolValue = true;
        AppState.StringValue = "Testing 123...";
    }
}
```

Everything works as expected and the menu item is visible as well as the string value in the H2 tag.

However if I add a call to my Javasript function via JSRuntime like so:

```
@code
{
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var jwtToken = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("getCookie", "cookieName");

        AppState.BoolValue = true;
        AppState.StringValue = "Testing 123...";
    }
}
```

The javascript runs, and the AppState values are updated (I added a console log to test this) **BUT** the navigation does not update to show the menu item and the H2 tag does not show the new string value...

If you navigate to a page in the menu the state will update, but it won't again if you do a hard refresh....

I tried adding a **StateHasChanged()** call but this did not work:

```
@code
{
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var jwtToken = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("getCookie", "cookieName");

        AppState.BoolValue = true;
        AppState.StringValue = "Testing 123...";
        StateHasChanged(); // Does not work!
    }
}
```

Since the state seemed to update after navigating I also tried forcing a navigation event, also to no avail:

```
@code
{
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var jwtToken = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("getCookie", "cookieName");

        AppState.BoolValue = true;
        AppState.StringValue = "Testing 123...";

        var uri = new Uri(NavigationManager.Uri).GetComponents(UriComponents.PathAndQuery, UriFormat.Unescaped);
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo(uri);
    }
}
```

I'm continuing to try a few other things but nothing seems to work. **StateHasChanged()** really should have been the fix for something like this in my understanding. Anything else I should try?

**UPDATE**

As enet pointed out I need to notify downstream components when the state has changed. It wasn't the JSRuntime that caused an issue - but it was the DELAY that it created within App.razor that resulted in the object state seeming to be different on a hard refresh. In the first scenario the object was updated BEFORE the other components started rendering so they used the already updated state. But once there was any kind of delay (a call to JSRuntime for example) they required a notification in order to update their state because they had a chance to render prior to the delay using the older state. I replaced the JSRuntime call with a Task.Delay() of a few milliseconds and it resulted in the same issue! Adding a trigger to the event resolved this.

Comment: The main issue with your code is how to call the StateHasChanged method and from where. I'm going to post an existing code sample which demonstrate it. Just run the code, and see how components communicate with a service, and how they are being re-rendered, then if you have question, don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### MessageService.cs

```
 public class MessageService
{
    private string message;
    public string Message
    {
        get => message;
        set
        {
            if (message != value)
            {
                message = value;
                if (Notify != null)
                {
                     Notify?.Invoke();
                }

            }
        }
    }

    public event Action Notify;
}
```

Note: The service is a normal class... It provides services to other objects, and it should be added to the DI container in Startup.ConfigureServices method to make it available to requesting clients. Add this: to the ConfigureServices method:

```
 services.AddScoped<MessageService>();
```

Note: As you can see I define an event delegate of the Action type, which is invoked from the property's set accessor, when the user type text into a text box in Component3. Triggering this delegate causes the text entered by Components3 to be displayed in the Index component which is the parent of Component2 (see code below).

### Index.razor

```
  @page "/"

  @inject MessageService MessageService
  @implements IDisposable
  @inject IJSRuntime  JSRuntime

  <p>
   I'm the parent of Component2. I've got a message from my grand 
   child: @MessageService.Message
  </p>

  <Component2 />
  <p>@jwtToken</p>

  @code {
    private string jwtToken;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
   {
       // await SetTokenAsync("my token");
       jwtToken = await GetTokenAsync();
       MessageService.Notify += OnNotify;
       MessageService.Message = "A message from Index";
    }

    public void OnNotify()
    {
    InvokeAsync(() =>
    {
        StateHasChanged();
    });
}

public void Dispose()
{
    MessageService.Notify -= OnNotify;
}

public async Task<string> GetTokenAsync()
       => await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("localStorage.getItem", "authToken");

public async Task SetTokenAsync(string token)
{
    if (token == null)
    {
        await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("localStorage.removeItem", "authToken");
    }
    else
    {
        await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("localStorage.setItem", "authToken", token);
    }


 }
}
```

Note that we directly bind to the MessageService.Message property, but the StateHasChanged method must be called to refresh the display of the text.

### Component2.razor

```
<h3>Component2: I'm the parent of component three</h3>
<Component3/>

@code {

}
```

### Component3.razor

```
 @inject MessageService MessageService

 <p>This is component3. Please type a message to my grand parent</p>
 <input placeholder="Type a message to grandpa..." type="text"
   @bind="@MessageService.Message" @bind:event="oninput" />

 @code {

     protected override void OnInitialized()
     {

        MessageService.Notify += () => InvokeAsync(() =>
        {
           StateHasChanged();
        });

     }
 }
```

Note that in Component3 we bind the MessageService.Message to a text box, and the binding occurs each time you press a key board( input event versus change 
 event).

That is all, hope this helps, and don't hesitate to ask any question.

Comment: Thank you enet. I implemented your code into a test solution and just like in my example it works... but once you make a call to JSRuntime it seems to block the DOM being updated by any state changes until you move to a different route. A hard refresh on the page blocks it again. This may be a bug and I submitted it to the Blazor/Asp.Net team.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're trying to say. Please, edit my answer to add the code which "seems to block the DOM being updated by any state changes ", and explain there what is the issue. I'll update my answer later on...

Comment: Thanks again enet. Did you try making a JSRuntime call to a Javascript function prior to updating a parameter on your MessageService like I outline in my question? That is key to my scenario. Aside from that both your code and my original code run as expected. If you go over the exact steps I outlined in my question you'll see what I mean. Everything works as expected until the JSRuntime call to the "getCookie()" function is introduced into the mix.

Comment: Yes, I've done it. It works perfectly well. I'll add the code to my answer. Compare it with the code which you added to my code answer, claiming that it results in the same problem. The issue with your code is how you call the StateHasChanged.

Comment: I will try that. Will report back ASAP. Thank you.

Comment: OK. I implemented your code EXACTLY. Notice when you first go to the page the text box is empty and has the placeholder copy? But if you click on "Counter" in the menu and click back to "Home" is now uses  "A message from Index" as it should have to begin with? This is what I am talking about! Now do a hard refresh and it's gone. So the first time you go to the page it ignores the fact that you updated the message until you force a DOM update by using the router! PERPLEXING EH?

Comment: ....And if you comment out the line "await SetTokenAsync("my token");" it does bind to the text box from the beginning. Even on a hard refresh.

Comment: Nothing perplexing...Perhaps the coincidence of my sample surprisingly written  (a couple of days before as an answer to a question) to fit your baseless assumption. I've changed my code a little bit, and now you can see the text in the text box when you go to the home page the first time. Again, this code was not written in an answer to your question. Now it is working as YOU expected...Nothing to do with JSInterop. Run the code and see for yourself.

Comment: Once again, the issue with your code is how you call the StateHasChanged method. It is related to the so-called SynchronizationContext

Comment: I appreciate the effort enet. The perplexing part is that when you don't use JSRuntime it binds automatically without requiring event handlers on dependent component on first run. This still seems like a bug to me. That single call to JSRuntime seems to have created the need to add all that extra event handler logic. But if you don't use JSRuntime the binding flows through the components on it's own. Having to add event handler logic to every component in the future does not seem like very elegant long term solution.

Comment: No, it's not a bug. And once again, it has nothing to do with JSRuntime, not directly. Read the following to understand why you should invoke the stateHasChanged as I did...https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components?view=aspnetcore-3.1#invoke-component-methods-externally-to-update-state

Comment: Thank you again. This document along with your code has made it clear what my issue was. It wasn't the JSRuntime that caused an issue - but it was the DELAY that it created within App.razor. In the first scenario the Object was updated BEFORE the other components started rendering so they used the updated state. But once there was any kind of delay they required a notification in order to update their state. I replaced the JSRuntime call with a Task.Delay() and it resulted in the same issue!